# Junit 5 - No ParameterResolver registered for parameter in constructor

Tags: java, oop, junit5

I'm trying to write a unit test to an abstract class using [junit5](/questions/tagged/junit5).

```
public class AbstractArrayStorageTest { 

private Storage storage; 

public static final String UUID_1 = "uuid1";

 public static final Resume RESUME_1 = new Resume(UUID_1);

public AbstractArrayStorageTest(Storage storage) {
    this.storage = storage;
}

@BeforeEach
public void setUp() {
    storage.clear();
    storage.save(RESUME_1);
}

@Test
public void size()  {
}
```

`Storage is an interface that AbstractArrayStorage implements.`

```
public abstract class AbstractArrayStorage implements Storage {
    protected static final int STORAGE_LIMIT = 10000;

    protected Resume[] storage = new Resume[STORAGE_LIMIT];
    protected int size = 0;
//some methods and abstract mehods
```

`

I always get

```
No ParameterResolver registered for parameter [ru.javawebinar.basejava.storage.Storage arg0] in constructor [basejava.storage.AbstractArrayStorageTest(basejava.storage.Storage)].
```

I tried to invoke storage in a method but revieved smth like this.storage = null message. I also tried to write parametrized test but it didn't work.

Comment: The problem seems to be with accepting storage as an argument in the test's constructor. JUnit can't figure out what value to provide for it. Why don't you just create the storage in the constructor and get rid of the argument?

Comment: Or even better, create a new storage in the setUp method so you have a brand-new instance of `Storage` for each tests (so all tests are isolated from each other, no side effect of a test on another).

Comment: As I understand, I have to implement all the methods from the interface when I'm creating instance of storage